# Quality problem when converting JPEG to GIF using FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I created a GIF using FFmpeg as shown below.
However, there is a problem with GIF quality. As you can see in the attachment, there are square particles on the GIF surface. I want to improve this.

- Is it possible to solve this problem with the FFmpeg default option without using the palette option?

Can I erase the repeating rectangle pattern shown in the GIF?

- "-f", "image2", "-i", "load_path", "-vf", "scale=720x450", "-y", "save_path"

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Sty.gif" width="500" height="300">
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2Sty.gif)

Comment: Do you mean MPEG? JPEGs aren't animated. GIFs are low quality and can only support 256 colors at most. They're also huge for what they contain. You should consider using MP4 or WebM.

Comment: http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html  Also, look into gifv container which IIRC is just mp4

Comment: Can I erase the repeating rectangle pattern shown in the GIF?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the palette* filters?